# I would like to read $_FILES with a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, php

Here is part of my Javascript function:

```
  var x=document.getElementById('DigitalFiles').rows[R].cells;
  x[0].innerHTML=   $_FILES['files']['name'][1]  <<<<  this $_FILES is not working !
```

What syntax will work, please.

Comment: No syntax will work.  The JavaScript is executed entirely on the client, and has no knowledge of `$_FILES`.  What is it you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: is your js is embedded in a php file?

Comment: If you are trying to get the filename from a form input, that would more easily be done with the input's `value=` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing javascript with PHP or vice versa.

To set `x[0].innerHTML` to the desired value, you could use this:

```
x[0].innerHTML=<?php echo $_FILES['files']['name'][1]; ?>;
```

Or, if you are already generating the javascript code directly in PHP:

```
<?php
    echo 'x[0].innerHTML="'.addslashes($_FILES['files']['name'][1]).'"';
?>
```

**Generally**

You cannot loop through a PHP array in javascript - unless you first make it's contents available to javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _arrayFromPhp=[<?php
        implode(',', $_arrayInPhp);
    ?>];
</script>
```

This would work, generally, so that you can then use `_arrayFromPhp` in your javascript environment. This rather abstract example also assumes that `$_arrayInPhp` is an array with only one level.

However, in the particular case of $_FILES this doesn't make much sense because PHP fills the $_FILES array with files that are being uploaded by the client. I cannot think of any purposeful way to process the contents of $_FILES in javascript.

If you want to use it anyway, you could go about it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _arrayFromPhp=<?php
       json_encode($_FILES);
    ?>;
</script>
```

After which `_arrayFromPhp` would contain a representation of `$_FILES` in javascript.

**Note**

If you want to somehow work with previously uploaded files in your javascript environment, you should first handle the upload in PHP itself (where `$_FILES` comes to play) and then apply something like the aforementioned solution to get your information from PHP into your javascript environment.

Please also note that `$_FILES` will only contain anything if the script is being called directly through the upload process. If you upload files and then reload the page (for example), `$_FILES` will be empty.

**Hint**

In case you are using a conventional upload form, please make sure that your form is set to the correct encoding type (by setting the attribute **enctype**):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. @user3063795 Check my explanation below as to the differences between PHP and JS in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

The $_FILES variable is specific to PHP and not JS. If you want to use JS you will have some restrictions to deal with. You may check out some HTML5 file handling at this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access

Answer (score 0):

Let me just expand on the difference between `PHP` and `Javascript` (in this context).

This is a simplified flow;

Client (your or someone else's browser) requests the website at myURL.com. This requests hits your server (`LAMP` stack for instance) and `Apache` routes this request to the right place, and `PHP` is executed on your server and this generates `HTML`. But really, this "HTML" is just a plain string. PHP does not know what HTML is, or anything about it, and when you are echo-ing or printing etc HTML from PHP, PHP just thinks of it as a string.

`PHP` has the ability to interact with the `database` (M in LAMP for `MySQL` - in this imaginary case) as well as some server variables (`$_SERVER` and `$_POST/GET`). Once all the `PHP` executes and creates your HTML, it sends this HTML as a simple string to the client browser.

The browser gets this string and then it begins to interpret it as HTML. It reads the HTML and will start downloading your assets like javascript files, `CSS` files, images etc etc and begins to pull all this together. So your javascript file gets read and executed and you CSS begins to style the HTML. The Javascript can continue running on the client, or be triggered to run certain functions by certain events (clicking, timing, scrolling etc).

As you can see, the client has NO access to running PHP. All the PHP has run on the server, and returned a string. All the client does is execute Javascript, in simple terms.

Now as things get a bit more advanced you can start using `AJAX`. AJAX is a combination of technologies (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) which is used to make requests to servers without reloading or redirecting the client to a new page. What this means is that you can have your client be at myURL.com and make an AJAX request to myURL.com/myAJAXHandler.php. The client stays at myURL.com, however the server basically sees it the client trying to access the myURL.com/myAJAXHandler.php page in the browser. The server does its normal thing, runs whatever PHP is at that address, and again, returns a simple string to the client. The client using Javascript gets this string and can do what it wants with it, which is usually updating the current page (still myURL.com) or any number of things.

This is a simplified explanation and I've left a lot of things out and generalised a lot but I'm just trying to give you a general idea of what happens.

Hope this helped.